# Cardinality of the set of Boolean subalgebras of the lattice of projections on a Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I have a simple question I've managed to get myself quite confused about.

Given a Hilbert space H, what do we know about the cardinality of

(a) the set $P(H)$ of projection operators onto $H$ (equivalently, the set of all closed subspaces of $H$),

and

(b) the set of all Boolean subalgebras of $P(H)$?

I imagine that if $H$ is separable, we can say more than we could otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to a unitary isomorphism, a Hilbert space is uniquely determined by its dimension, and closed subspaces are Hilbert spaces in their own right. So $P(H)$ is the disjoint union, over all cardinal numbers $\alpha \leq \dim(H)$, of closed subspaces of dimension $\alpha$. And there as many of the latter as unitary operators on a Hilbert space of dimension $\alpha$.

So in finite dimension, $\mathrm{card}(P(H)) = \sum_{\alpha=1}^{\dim(H)} \mathrm{card}(U(\alpha)) = \mathrm{card}(U(\dim(H))) = \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{R})$.

In infinite dimension, the unitary group $U(H)$ of $B(H)$ injects into the C*-algebra $B(H)$ of bounded operators on $H$. Also, any element of $B(H)$ is a linear combination of four unitaries, so there is a surjection $U(H)^4 \times \mathbb{C}^4 \to B(H)$. Hence $\mathrm{card}(P(H))=\mathrm{card}(U(H))=\mathrm{card}(B(H))=\max(\dim(H),\mathrm{card}(\mathbb{R}))$.

So regardless of dimension, $P(H)$ has cardinality $\max(\dim(H), 2^{\aleph_0})$.

Any Boolean subalgebra of $P(H)$ is contained in a maximal one, and those are all induced as the powerset of a choice of orthonormal basis. Hence the cardinality of the set of all Boolean subalgebras of $P(H)$ is $2^{2^{\mathrm{card}(P(H))}}$.

Comment: Thanks Chris. That's really helpful. But there's one thing I don't understand. By $\mathbb{R}$, do you mean the reals? Because it seems weird that for a finite dimensional Hilbert space, P(H) should be uncountable. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @BenEva A Hilbert space of finite dimension 2 or more has continuum many projection operators.  For example, the Euclidean plane has a projection operator to each line through the origin (plus the zero and identity operators).

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Dosen't this mean that if H is an infinite dimension seperable hilbert space, then $card(P(H))$ = $dim(H) = card(\mathbb{N})$, and so an infinite dimensional seperable hilbert space has fewer closed subspaces than a finite dimensional hilbert space?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was being sloppy there, edited it now.

Comment: ah, thanks, makes perfect sense now.

Comment: The last sentence of your answer is incorrect: a powerset Boolean algebra $\mathcal{P}(X)$ on a set $X$ has $2^{2^{|X|}}$ different subalgebras.  Indeed, it has $2^{2^{|X|}}$ ultrafilters, and (for instance) each pair of ultrafilters gives rise to a distinct subalgebra consisting of the subsets that are either in both ultrafilters or neither.  So there are actually $2^{2^{\mathrm{dim}(H)}}$ Boolean algebras of projections.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey - But presumably the join in the Boolean subalgebra is not the set-theoretic union, but rather comes from taking the least closed subspace spanned?